# redirect url in IIS 8.5

Tags: url, redirect, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting

I want to redirect a url
when user request http://192.168.0.1, this url redirect to http://192.168.0.1/aaa/bbb

I use PHP In IIS

Comment: I solve this problem with use a PHP Code, I Create a Index.php File and putted on main root and used this code if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/'){
header('Location: /aaa/bbb');
exit(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Create a Index.php File and putted on main root and used this code if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/'){ header('Location: /aaa/bbb'); exit();